# Using a locally installed module inside terraform cloud module

Tags: terraform, github-actions, cicd

I have a locally installed provider that is being used inside of a published terraform cloud module within our private repo.

The issue presents itself when running inside github actions.

Module_1 uses provider. The provider is installed through github actions to the local terraform provider directories(shown below)

When I try to use module_1 I get errors related to the provider being unable to be sourced.

Provider Definition inside module_1

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~>1.6"
  required_providers {
    provider = {
      source  = "local/org/provider"
      version = "2.2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "provider" {

}
```

The provider is installed to the local terraform plugins directory as expected through github actions. I have verified the path as:

```bash
/github/home/.terraform.d/plugins/local/org/provider/2.2.0/linux_amd64/provider
```

To use module_1 I have the following declaration

```
module "module_1" {
  source                 = "app.terraform.io/org/repo/module_1"
  version                = "0.0.13"  
}
```

When I run terraform init I get the following error:

```bash
 Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Upgrading modules...
Downloading app.terraform.io/org/repo/module_1 0.0.13 for provider...
- module_1 in .terraform/modules/module_1

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding local/org/provider versions matching ">= 2.2.0"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ local/org/provider: could not connect to local: failed to request
│ discovery document: Get "https://local/.well-known/terraform.json": EOF
```

I can use the provider through github actions when it is part of the "base" terraform and defined there. However, when the local provider is required as part of the downloaded module "module_1" it fails.

Comment: You should publish that provider: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/registry/providers/publishing ... that way you can use the url in the source and "everyone" can find it